# How can I prepare JSON for post request in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I need to send POST request with JSON body. In this point I assume I can't prepare JSON correctly. I searched about that but most of answers using Alomofire but I don't want to use it for this little work. Here I need JSON is:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": "5f52348e21e9b0e8994df1de",
            "amount": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "5f52348e8299dce0d0e393f8",
            "amount": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I have createJSON function and in this function I get ids and amounts in my `sepeteEklenenUrunler` array at `for loop`. And after that I send created array which is mainArr send to `sendDataToService` function.

Here my createJSON function:

```
func createJSON(){
    var postArr = [[String : Any]]()
    var mainArr = [String:Any]()
    for i in ViewController.sepetEklenenUrunler {
        print(i.id)
        print(i.stock)
        var data = ["id":i.id, "amount":i.stock] as [String : Any]
        //print(data)
        postArr.append(data)
    }
    mainArr = ["products" : postArr] as [String : Any]
    
    
    sendDataToService(dataArr: mainArr)

    
}
```

After that function my `mainArr` is:

```
["products": [["amount": 1, "id": "5f52348ee6fc340d2feb412b"], ["amount": 2, "id": "5f52348e8299dce0d0e393f8"]]]
```

And lastly I send to request with that function:

```
func sendDataToService(dataArr : [String : Any]){
 
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataArr, options: [])


    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: "myserviceurl")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON)
            print("response here!!")
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

But after all of that my JSON body is wrong because service response is "empty cart". How can I change my mainArr to I needed JSON (top of the question json)? I need advices and help.

Comment: I think json dictionary is fine. Try to add option in JSONSerialization.data

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataArr, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
```

Comment: @RajaKishan I added but response was same empty cart.

Comment: Okay. Try to call API in Postman and you will get full code for the swift API request.

Comment: I saw it now. I don't know about headers. I forgot headers in this code. Thanks for advice and help @RajaKishan.

Comment: Yes. I think you have to set Content-Type as "application/json"

Comment: It solved. Can you write your advices in answer so we can close to question.

Comment: Are these issues in the header?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. I saw headers in Postman's full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are possible issues in code. For correct API call request try to call API first in postman and postman has a feature to generate code for the request to identify the issues in code. It might be missing some parameters in the header.
Set header value :

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```